# Bitshift << and multiplication * precedence

Tags: go, operator-precedence

Tried this code [on Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FW6tBBSbG31):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    log2Dim := uint32(9)
    
    SIZE := 1 << 3 * log2Dim
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", SIZE)
    
    SIZE = 1 << (3 * log2Dim)            // => only difference: adding ( )
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v\n", SIZE)
}
```

This is printed out:

```
Result: 72
Result: 134217728
```

Why does it make a huge difference just adding `( )` to the statement containing `<<` and `*` operations?

According to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/go/go_operators_precedence.htm), `*` has higher precedence over `<<`, which is Google first result searching for *bitshift precedence golang*.

Comment: The language specification (https://golang.org/ref/spec) is a very easy read compared to most programming languages. It's the first place I look when I can't understand the syntax or behavior of a language feature.

Comment: The site you found is of low quality. They're showing a C operator precedence table: not only are some of the precedences wrong there, but also there's operators like `sizeof` which exist in C but not in go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page you linked to is wrong. There is only one spec for Go and it's pretty clear about [operator precedence](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators):

> There are five precedence levels for binary operators. Multiplication  operators bind strongest, followed by addition operators, comparison  operators, && (logical AND), and finally || (logical OR):
>
> ```
>     5             *  /  %  <<  >>  &  &^
>     4             +  -  |  ^
>     3             ==  !=  <  <=  >  >=
>     2             &&
>     1             ||
> ```
>
> Binary operators of the same precedence associate from left to right. For instance, x / y * z is the same as (x / y) * z.

Multiplication and bitshift are at the same precedence level so the "left to right" rule applies, making your code the equivalent of `(1 << 3) * log2Dim`

Note that *left to right* means *in the code*, not *in the precedence table*. This is seen by the example given in the spec.

Comment: That link is #1 by "go operator precedence" query in google. Spec is #2, but what a shame! Thank you for underlining that they are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are five precedence levels for binary operators. `*` and `<<` have the same precedence level: 5. Binary operators of the same precedence associate from left to right, so `1 << 3 * log2Dim` is equivalent to `(1 << 3) * log2Dim`.

Source: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators